# Flask wtforms Date and Time, picker available for new entry, but not for update, despite same template

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I can create a date and time entry for a new post entry which successfully saves. However the date and time entry widget is not available when I would like to update and make changes. I do not understand why. The new and update route use the same crete_post.html template. I have included this template, routes.py and forms.py below.

create_post.html

```
...

<div class="form-group">
                    <h5> Date and Time</h5>
                    {% if form.date_posted.errors %}
                        {{ form.date_posted(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.date_posted.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.date_posted }}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if form.time_posted.errors %}
                        {{ form.time_posted(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.time_posted.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.time_posted }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
...
```

routes.py

```
...

@app.route("/post/new", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_post():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(title=form.title.data,
                    description=form.description.data,
                    status=form.status.data,
                    priority=form.priority.data,
                    date_posted=form.date_posted.data,
                    time_posted=form.time_posted.data,
                    assigned_to=form.assigned_to.data,
                    reported_by=form.reported_by.data)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post has been created!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('create_post.html', title='New Post', form=form,
                legend='New Post')

@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>")
def post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    return render_template('post.html', title=post.title, post=post)

@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>/update", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# @login_required
def update_post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post.title = form.title.data
        post.description = form.description.data
        post.date_posted=form.date_posted.data,
        post.time_posted=form.time_posted.data,
        post.status = form.status.data
        post.priority = form.priority.data
        post.assigned_to = form.assigned_to.data
        post.reported_by = form.reported_by.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post has been updated!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home', post_id=post.id))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.title.data = post.title
        form.description.data = post.description
        form.date_posted = post.date_posted
        form.time_posted = post.time_posted
        form.status.data = post.status
        form.priority.data = post.priority
        form.assigned_to.data = post.assigned_to
        form.reported_by.data = post.reported_by
    return render_template('create_post.html', title='Update Post',
            form=form, legend ='Update Post')
```

forms.py

```
status_options = [('ongoing', 'ongoing'), ('completed', 'completed')]
priority_options = [('moderate', 'moderate'),('high', 'high'),('low','low')]
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField('Description')
    date_posted  = DateField('Date')
    time_posted  = TimeField('Time')
    status = SelectField('Status',choices = status_options)
    priority = SelectField('Priority',choices = priority_options)
    assigned_to = StringField('Assigned To')
    reported_by = StringField('Reported By')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

**Currently:**

models.py

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
#    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
#    time_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
date_posted = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
time_posted = db.Column(db.Time, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    priority = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    assigned_to = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    reported_by = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

forms.py

```
status_options = [('ongoing', 'ongoing'), ('completed', 'completed')]
priority_options = [('moderate', 'moderate'),('high', 'high'),('low','low')]
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField('Description')
    date_posted  = DateField('Date',format='%Y-%m-%d')
    time_posted  = TimeField('Time',format='%H-%M')
    #time_posted  = TimeField('Time',format='%H:%M:%S')
    #time_posted  = TimeField('Time',format='%H:%M')
    #time_posted  = TimeField('Time',format='%h:%m:%s')
    status = SelectField('Status',choices = status_options)
    priority = SelectField('Priority',choices = priority_options)
    assigned_to = StringField('Assigned To')
    reported_by = StringField('Reported By')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

routes.py

```
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>/update", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# @login_required
def update_post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    # if post.author != current_user:
    #     abort(403)
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post.title = form.title.data
        post.description = form.description.data
        post.date_posted=form.date_posted.data,
        post.time_posted=form.time_posted.data,
        post.status = form.status.data
        post.priority = form.priority.data
        post.assigned_to = form.assigned_to.data
        post.reported_by = form.reported_by.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post has been updated!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home', post_id=post.id))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.title.data = post.title
        form.description.data = post.description
        form.date_posted.data = post.date_posted
        #form.time_posted.data = post.time_posted
        form.time_posted.data = (datetime.datetime.min + post.time_posted).time()
        form.status.data = post.status
        form.priority.data = post.priority
        form.assigned_to.data = post.assigned_to
        form.reported_by.data = post.reported_by
    return render_template('create_post.html', title='Update Post',
            form=form, legend ='Update Post')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got two issues here:

- you didn't set the `data` members of the date and time fields
- time is a `datetime.timedelta` value, i.e. the time elapsed since the epoch

You have to convert the `datetime.timedelta` value to `datetime.time`.

---

Edit:

Now that you've shown the definition of the `Post` class, I can see the database fields are:

```
date_posted = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
time_posted = db.Column(db.Time, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

So this should work:

```
form.date_posted.data = post.date_posted
form.time_posted.data = post.time_posted
```

Something else you can try:

```
form = PostForm(request.form)
if form.validate_on_submit():
    form.populate_obj(post)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented these changes. There seems to be a final issue in the format of the time. I have added this additional info to the question, at the bottom. Thank you

Comment: @Ollie Small change: can you try converting time to `datetime.datetime` as my shown above.

Comment: Thanks I have already changed this, it still results in the invalid time error.

Comment: @Ollie Try `TimeField('Time',format='%H-%M')` I think the hyphen is important if you're using wtforms.fields.html5. Plus revert the change I suggested last time.

Comment: That’s not making any difference. I have updated the question. Under ‘currently’ is the position of the scripts. Thanks

Comment: @Ollie I think `time_posted` should be `db.Column(db.Time,..)`. Also check that definition matches with your database, i,e, it is a time field.

Comment: date_posted is type date and time_posted is type time in database (checked on MySQL server). and the Models.py date_posted = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    time_posted = db.Column(db.Time, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

Comment: Error running WSGI application
2020-05-14 13:02:14,949: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213859/discussion-between-jignatius-and-ollie).

Comment: @Ollie Another suggestion for you. See above.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. The last thing you suggested finally got it working 

Answer (score 0):

In this :

```
elif request.method == 'GET':
    form.title.data = post.title
    form.description.data = post.description
    form.date_posted = post.date_posted
    form.time_posted = post.time_posted
    form.status.data = post.status
    form.priority.data = post.priority
    form.assigned_to.data = post.assigned_to
    form.reported_by.data = post.reported_by
return render_template('create_post.html', title='Update Post',
        form=form, legend ='Update Post')
```

".data" is missing in `form.date_posted` and `form.time_posted`. Change it as below:

```
    form.date_posted.data = post.date_posted
    form.time_posted.data = post.time_posted
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This caused an error: AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'. For the line: {{ form.time_posted }}.           File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 736, in _value
2020-05-04 11:04:03,464:     return self.data and self.data.strftime(self.format) or ''

Comment: ...probably an issue with the forms.py format?? I’ve tried a few solutions but not getting anywhere :/